# Publishing a website under IIS 7 and getting ��Y�o�8�}���x��� (odd characters)

Tags: iis, iis-7, web, publish

I just published working well website and try to browse it locally under IIS 7.

And I am facing some odd characters:

> ��Y�o�8�}���x���

and etc...

### How to fix it?

Comment: Some information could help (code, encodings...)

Comment: @X.L.Ant the project is working fimnd locally and with the same web.config I am publishing and try to browse it. And it is not working at all. Thats what I know so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution I have found is to change APP POOL to v.2, because my project is done for ASP.NET 3.5